# Having trouble by MFC lntelliSense on C++

Tags: c++, mfc, usb

Hello I have this Microsoft Foundation Classes that will run mostly and check USB Device and other stuff. The problem is, certain IntelliSense is undefined that's why most errors will display when running the program.

**Here's the error list:**

[image]

**The Entire Code:**

```
// MFCApplication2Dlg.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MFCApplication2.h"
#include "MFCApplication2Dlg.h"
#include "afxdialogex.h"
#include "afxwin.h"
#include "CyAPI.h"
#define UART_H

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

bool IsConnect = false;
// CAboutDlg dialog used for App About

class CAboutDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
    CAboutDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_ABOUTBOX };

    protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

CAboutDlg::CAboutDlg() : CDialogEx(CAboutDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CAboutDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CAboutDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg dialog



CMFCApplication2Dlg::CMFCApplication2Dlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialogEx(CMFCApplication2Dlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication2Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// CMFCApplication2Dlg message handlers

BOOL CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialogEx::OnInitDialog();

    // Add "About..." menu item to system menu.

    // IDM_ABOUTBOX must be in the system command range.
    ASSERT((IDM_ABOUTBOX & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX);
    ASSERT(IDM_ABOUTBOX < 0xF000);

    CMenu* pSysMenu = GetSystemMenu(FALSE);
    if (pSysMenu != NULL)
    {
        BOOL bNameValid;
        CString strAboutMenu;
        bNameValid = strAboutMenu.LoadString(IDS_ABOUTBOX);
        ASSERT(bNameValid);
        if (!strAboutMenu.IsEmpty())
        {
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_SEPARATOR);
            pSysMenu->AppendMenu(MF_STRING, IDM_ABOUTBOX, strAboutMenu);
        }
    }

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnSysCommand(UINT nID, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nID & 0xFFF0) == IDM_ABOUTBOX)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlgAbout;
        dlgAbout.DoModal();
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnSysCommand(nID, lParam);
    }
}

// If you add a minimize button to your dialog, you will need the code below
//  to draw the icon.  For MFC applications using the document/view model,
//  this is automatically done for you by the framework.

void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if (IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
}

// The system calls this function to obtain the cursor to display while the user drags
//  the minimized window.
HCURSOR CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnQueryDragIcon()
{
    return static_cast<HCURSOR>(m_hIcon);
}


bool CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{

    USBDevice->Open(0);

    if (USBDevice->IsOpen() != TRUE)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Failed to Open Device"));
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        IsConnect = true;
        return true;
    }
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3()
{
    USBDevice->Close();
    IsConnect = false;
}


void CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton2()
{
    char tmpUart[60];
    long OutPacketSize;
    OutPacketSize = sizeof(sUart);

    LPTSTR pBuffer;
    CString sBuffer;
    int i;

    if (IsConnect == false)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("USB Connect Fail"));
        return;
    }

    CEdit*OutValue = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_OUT_VALUE);

    pBuffer = sBuffer.GetBuffer(60);
    OutValue->GetWindowText(pBuffer, 60);

    strcpy(tmpUart, pBuffer);

    OutPacketSize = strlen(tmpUart);

    for (i = 0; i<OutPacketSize; i++) sUart[i] = tmpUart[i];

    sUart[OutPacketSize + 1] = 0;
    OutPacketSize = OutPacketSize + 1;

    //Perform the BULK OUT

    if (USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt)
    {
        USBDevice->BulkOutEndPt->XferData(sUart, OutPacketSize);
    }

}
```

**HELP:**

What certain libraries do I have to import or include to fix these kind of errors? I'm new to MFC's and I don't quite yet understand the structures and ways to program this. Please help.

Comment: Please confirm that line 68 of _mfcapplication2dlg.cpp_ is `ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CMFCApplication2Dlg::OnBnClickedButton3)`, and edit your question to m ake that clear.

Comment: BTW: Intellisense has nothing to do with your problem. Your problem is simply that your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

The [ON_BN_CLICKED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dtww101.aspx) message map macro expects a member function pointer with the signature

```cpp
afx_msg void memberFxn()
```

However, your `OnBnClickedButton1` returns a `bool`. That member function must not have a return value (`void`) to use it with `ON_BN_CLICKED`.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano: I already told you, how to fix this: Change the function signature of the offending member function to not return a `bool`.

Comment: Even if I change it, the error is always there sir. I change it from `bool` to `void` and remove the `return false` and `return true` line of code. But still, it doesn't work.

Comment: @laurencekeithalbano: *"It doesn't work"* is not an error description. It may not compile, but fail with a different compiler (or linker) error. That's not what this question is asking for, though. If you need help with another issue, ask a new question.

Comment: Ok @IInspectable . Thank you for your help.